# Drag working only horizontally

Tags: d3.js, drag, force-layout

I have a node which is connected to approximately  5 other nodes then i am able to drag that node in any direction , but if the connected nodes count increase say about 50, then drag of that node happens only in horizontal direction , not able to drag that node vertically .I use force layout .

What needs to be done.
Thanks in advance

This is code :

```
 scope.force.on("tick", function(e) {        
                        var ky = 1.2 * e.alpha; 
          // scope.currentLinks are all links in graph 
                        scope.currentLinks.forEach(function(d, i) { 
// d.source.properties.UI_HIERARCHY or d.target.properties.UI_HIERARCHY value ranges from 0 to 4
                     d.source.y += ((4 -(d.source.properties.UI_HIERARCHY)) * 80 - d.source.y) * ky;
                     d.target.y += ((4 -(d.target.properties.UI_HIERARCHY)) * 80 - d.target.y) * ky;
                        });
                        scope.link.attr("x1", function (d) {
                                return d.source.x+15;
                            })
                            .attr("y1", function (d) {
                                return d.source.y+15;
                            })
                            .attr("x2", function (d) {
                                return d.target.x+15;
                            })
                            .attr("y2", function (d) {
                                return d.target.y+15;
                            });

                            scope.node.attr("transform", function (d) {
                                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                            });    
                    }  
                });
```

Comment: You'd need to post some code or a fiddle, this isn't something that can be answered with just the details you've provided.

Comment: Hi Elijah , I have edited post to add code changes that i have

Answer (score 0):

Where that happens lock `y` value. 
Probably in `d.source.y` or `d.target.y` for link. Probably `y` significantly small compared to the `15` and because `function (d) {return d.target.y+15;}` always return `~15`.

This may occur in a different place, not only in `tick()`.

See `console.log()` via drag:

```
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
      console.log("y1 " + d.source.y+15);        
      return d.source.y+15;
    })                              
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
       console.log("y2 " +d.target.y+15);        
       return d.target.y+15;
   });
```

**UPD:**

```
if (e.type !== "drag") {

    var ky = 1.2 * e.alpha; 
    scope.currentLinks.forEach(function(d, i) { 
        d.source.y += ((4 -(d.source.properties.UI_HIERARCHY)) * 80 - d.source.y) * ky;
        d.target.y += ((4 -(d.target.properties.UI_HIERARCHY)) * 80 - d.target.y) * ky;
    });                        

}

scope.node.attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
});  

scope.link.attr("x1", function (d) {
    return d.source.x+15;
})
.attr("y1", function (d) {
    return d.source.y+15;
})
.attr("x2", function (d) {
    return d.target.x+15;
})
.attr("y2", function (d) {
   return d.target.y+15;
});
```

Comment: Hi Evgeniy, What do you mean by "lock" y value ? where all do i need to do this ?

Comment: I mean then `y` is fixed value (probably approximate to ~15). See your `tick()` function. And you can use condition `if (d3.event.type !== "drag"))` for disable your calculation of `y + e.alpha` and return `d.(source||target).y` only without `+=`....